# How to use Drupal Code Sniffer in windows?

Tags: 7

How do you configure and use [Drupal Code Sniffer](http://drupal.org/project/drupalcs) in Windows?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  The instructions vary per IDE.

Comment: eclipse n notepad

Answer (score 2):

On the project page there are instructions for each IDE.

The one you're after (Eclipse) is [here](http://drupal.org/node/1420004).

In case anyone uses something else, the other instructions are as follows:

[Vim, Sublime Text, and Komodo](http://drupal.org/node/1419996)

[Netbeans](http://drupal.org/node/1420008)

[PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html) (install the Codeing Standards globally first, as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419988), then Drupal should be available in the list or rulesets.

You won't get this working in Notepad.

On another note, I'd probably also just stop using Notepad.  If you must use a basic tool, then [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a million times better.

Comment: PHPStorm not mentioned. Disappointed.

Comment: @ssibal I've added a link to the docs for PHPStorm :)

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal Code sniffer](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalcs) has been merged into [Coder 7.x-2.x](http://drupal.org/project/coder)! This project is deprecated and bugs should be reported to the coder issue queue.

---

For the installation of coder module here are the useful links

1. [Read Coder Module Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/144172)
2. [Installing Coder Sniffer](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419988)

There are many ways to install Code Sniffer i.e. via Composer, Pear or Drush. Following are the links to firstly install these packages.

1. [Composer's installation instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)
2. [PEAR's installation instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php)
3. [Drush's installation instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676)

Note: *Coder 7.x-2.x is only compatible with PHPCS 1.x. You need to use 8.x-2.x for PHPCS 2.x.*

As I am using Windows 7. I installed Code sniffer package via pear.

- [Installing Pear on Windows](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)
- Download the [coder module](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder). During writing of this Answer the version is 7.x-2.4

Answer (score -1):

You can try

[Drupal API for Dreamweaver](http://www.xtnd.us/dreamweaver/drupalapi)

[Drupal for Eclipse](http://www.xtnd.us/eclipse/drupal)